# Is there a way to show "Loading data.." option in Rally Grid(ext JS) while making the Ajax request to load the data?

Tags: ajax, extjs, rally

I am trying to set the message to "Data Loading.." whenever the data is loading in the grid. It is working fine if I don't make an Ajax call. But, when I try to make Ajax Request, It is not showing up the message "Loading data..", when it is taking time to load the data. Can someone please try to help me with this.. Thanks in Advance.

```
_loadData: function(x){
                var that = this;
                if(this.project!=undefined) {
                    this.setLoading("Loading data..");
                    this.projectObjectID = this.project.value.split("/project/");
                    var that = this;
                    this._ajaxCall().then( function(content) {
                        console.log("assigned then:",content,this.pendingProjects, content.data);
                        that._createGrid(content);
                    })
                }
            },
            _ajaxCall: function(){
                var deferred = Ext.create('Deft.Deferred');
                console.log("the project object ID is:",this.projectObjectID[1]);
                var that = this;
                console.log("User Reference:",that.userref,this.curLen);
                var userObjID = that.userref.split("/user/");
                Ext.Ajax.request({
                    url: 'https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/project/'+this.projectObjectID[1]+'/projectusers?fetch=true&start=1&pagesize=2000',
                    method: 'GET',
                    async: false,
                    headers:
                        {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                        },
                    success: function (response) {
                        console.log("entered the response:",response);
                        var jsonData = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                        console.log("jsonData:",jsonData);
                        var blankdata = '';
                        var resultMessage = jsonData.QueryResult.Results;
                        console.log("entered the response:",resultMessage.length);
                        this.CurrentLength = resultMessage.length;
                        this.testCaseStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.custom.Store', {
                            data:resultMessage
                        });
                        this.pendingProjects = resultMessage.length
                        console.log("this testcase store:",resultMessage);
                        _.each(resultMessage, function (data) {
                            var objID = data.ObjectID;
                            var column1 = data.Permission;
                            console.log("this result message:",column1);
                            if(userObjID[1]==objID) {
                                console.log("obj id 1 is:",objID);
                                console.log("User Reference 2:",userObjID[1]);
                                if (data.Permission != 'Editor') {
                                    deferred.resolve(this.testCaseStore);
                                }else{
                                    this.testCaseStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.custom.Store', {
                                        data:blankdata
                                    });
                                    deferred.resolve(this.testCaseStore);
                                }
                            }
                        },this)
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        deferred.reject(response.status);
                        Ext.Msg.alert('Status', 'Request Failed.');

                    }
                });
                return deferred;
            },
```

Answer (score 1):

The main issue comes from your Ajax request which is using 
    `async:false`

This is blocking the javascript (unique) thread.
Consider removing it if possible. Note that there is no guarantee XMLHttpRequest synchronous requests will be supported in the future.

You'll also have to add in your success and failure callbacks:
    `that.setLoading(false);`

Comment: Thank you so much Jean. Making async: true worked for me.